# When an infinite square well grows from $(0, a)$ to $(0, 2a)$, why do we integrate from $0$ to $2a$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential, probability, boundary-conditions

Say we have a particle in an infinite square well where $V= \infty$ if $x<0$ or $x>a$. Then, suppose the well expanded to $V= \infty$ if $x<0$ or $x>2a$. While the wave function is momentarily undisturbed, to find the probability of new possible states of the particle, we compute

$$c_n = \int_0^a \sqrt{\frac{2}{2a}}sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{2a}\right)\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}sin\left( \frac{\pi x}{a} \right)dx.$$

*I'm wondering why the bounds are from 0 to a and not 0 to 2a.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key words are "the wavefunction is momentarily undisturbed." Before the perturbation, the wavefunction is zero outside the range $0$ to $a$. Immediately after the perturbation, the wavefunction is unchanged, so it's still zero in the range $a$ to $2a$. You can write this a little more explicitly as:

$$\begin{align}
c_n &= \int_0^{2a} \sqrt{\frac{2}{2a}}sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{2a}\right)\psi(x)\,dx\\ &=\int_0^a \sqrt{\frac{2}{2a}}sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{2a}\right)\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}sin\left( \frac{\pi x}{a} \right)dx+\int_a^{2a}\sqrt{\frac{2}{2a}}sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{2a}\right) 0\,dx
\end{align}$$

where the second term clearly integrates to zero and thus can be left out entirely, leaving you with the expression in your question.